# How to create a dynamic URL for audio files using a for loop? Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I started learning to code recently and I'm having a problem with this self-challenge. My intent is to use a for-loop to cycle through the array containing color names, which represent buttons, to create a dynamic URL to audio files instead of individually adding the URL for the audio file to each button. Being a newbie, this code makes sense to me, but it isn't working. Using the browser "inspect" tool, I noticed the output for `buttonColours[i]` is coming out as **undefined**. Please help me understand why!!!

```
var buttonColours = ["red","blue","green","yellow"];
var sounds = [];

for (var i = 0; i < buttonColours.length; i++){

    $("."+buttonColours[i]+"").click(function(event){

        // Add sound when button is clicked
        sounds[i]= new Audio("sounds/"+buttonColours[i]+".mp3");
        sounds[i].play();

        // Add CSS class when button is clicked
        $(".red").addClass("pressed");
        setTimeout(function(){
            $(".red").removeClass("pressed");
        }, 200);
    });
}
```

Comment: When is the script being run?  The `$("."+buttonColours[i]+"").click(...` line will try to find an element on the page.  If the code runs before the page has loaded (eg,you have put it in a `<script>` tag in the `<head>` section of your page), the element won't exist and will be `undefined`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to right answer of Sachin Nayak, another way to solve this issue is to use `let` instead of `var`. `let` creates a variable inside the scope of the loop where `var` will be a global variable that will be overwritten at every iteration. That means that with `let` you don't overwrite the value, but create a new one at each iteration, thus the reference stays intact.

```
var buttonColours = ["red","blue","green","yellow"];
var sounds = [];

// Notice let i instead of var i.
for (let i = 0; i < buttonColours.length; i++) {

  $("." + buttonColours[i]).click(function(event) {

    // Add sound when button is clicked
    sounds[i] = new Audio("sounds/" + buttonColours[i] + ".mp3");
    sounds[i].play();

    // Add CSS class when button is clicked
    $(".red").addClass("pressed");
    setTimeout(function() {
      $(".red").removeClass("pressed");
    }, 200);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As the click function is a callback, the variable i may have changed before the callback occured. So you will have to bind the value of i to the function. Try this instead :

```
var buttonColours = ["red", "blue", "green", "yellow"];
var sounds = [];

for (var i = 0; i < buttonColours.length; i++) {

  $("." + buttonColours[i] + "").click(function(i, event) { // OBSERVE i have added i as a parameter

    // Add sound when button is clicked
    sounds[i] = new Audio("sounds/" + buttonColours[i] + ".mp3");
    sounds[i].play();

    // Add CSS class when button is clicked
    $(".red").addClass("pressed");
    setTimeout(function() {
      $(".red").removeClass("pressed");
    }, 200);
  }.bind(this, i)); // OBSERVE I have added an i here

}
```

One more problem you have in your code is that you have not initialized sounds array. I do not think it will error out, so I have not corrected it.

This article seems to be explaning the problem well : https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/javascript-callbacks-variable-scope-problem